# How do i attachment a file in the email notification

Tags: azure-logic-apps

In Blob storage there are multiple files. But I want to send a specific file(Transaction.xlsx) as a attachment
[image]

for a specific pipeline the file as to be attached in the specific pipeline.how it can be done in Logical app

```
Transaction pipeline=TRANSACTOIN.xlsx    
Master pipeline= MASTER.xlsx    
Invoice pipeline= INVOICE.xlsx
```

Please advise

Regards
Rohit

Comment: You got anything to show us so we don't have to start from scratch?

Comment: Need to have from scratch

Answer (score 0):

> How do i attachment a file in the email notification

I have followed below steps to send an attachment using logic Apps.

- Get list using List blobs in Azure logic apps like below
- I have used Loop for checking condition ( name == Transaction.xlsx).
- Then, if the condition is true, get the blob content and the and you use send an email action and then send the content as an attachment.

**Design:**

[image]

Comment: For_each and Name is hard coded or getting the value from some other action. This is my diagram

Comment: I am getting error The execution of template action 'For_each' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@items('For_each_2')?['Name']' is of type 'String'. The result must be a valid array.

Comment: You should take the value the list of blobs then this will work